# l3backend installed, but getting: "LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found" error

Tags: rmarkdown

I am unable to knit a pdf in RStudio. I have had no issues previously, though did recently update my Xcode installation. I am working on a Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6.

The problem seems to be related to my `l3backend` installation, as I get the error copied below. However, I have checked multiple ways and I certainly do have `l3backend` installed.

Here's the error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
tlmgr search --file --global '/l3backend-pdfmode.def'
! LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile handOut_fgkTests.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See handOut_fgkTests.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = !verbose) :
  Failed to find a package that contains l3backend-pdfmode.def
Execution halted
```

When I run:

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/l3backend-pdfmode.def'
```

I get:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
```

Running the Tex Live Utility also confirms `l3backend` is installed. I am at a total loss as to what is suddenly causing this error.

Comment: Is `l3backend` up-to-date? There was a file name change recently and perhaps you don't have that

Comment: Yes, I believe my ```l3backend``` install is up-to-date. I used Tex Live to reinstall this morning.

Comment: @JosephWright I have Release 2020-09-11.

Comment: OK, what do `kpsewhich l3backend-pdfmode.def` and `kpsewhich l3backend-pdftex.def` report?

Comment: ```kpsewhich l3backend-pdfmode.def``` returns nothing. ```kpsewhich l3backend-pdftex.def``` returns: ```/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def```

Comment: l3backend-pdfmode is the old file and l3backend-pdftex is its replacement so it not being there isn't unexpected but what is not clear from the log you have posted is which file is trying to access the old name. what command are you running that causes `tlmgr search --file --global '/l3backend-pdfmode.def'` to appear in the latex log that you show in the first code block above?

Comment: If expl3 is looking for the pdfmode file it is too old. Check if your latex format is up-to-date.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am clicking the `knit` in RStudio and this text precedes the error: ```/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS handOut_fgkTests.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output handOut_fgkTests.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua```

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you provide some guidance on how to check that my latex format is up-to-date?

Comment: what do you get on the terminal if you type `pdflatex \\stop` it should be `$ pdflatex \\stop
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get the same message EXCEPT I get: `L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>`

Comment: there you go then your format is too old, try `fmtutil-sys --all` to rebuild them

Comment: often the automatic remaking of formats fails because you have a locally installed old format somewhere that is masking the main one so if the above doesn't work show the output from  `kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: I now get `L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>`, but still an error when I knit: `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.` Running `kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` returns: `usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Everything is working now - last issue was with my markdown document. Thanks for your help!